# Combine bar chart and highlight when using Pandas Styler on the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

Is there a way to combine bar styler and highlight styler in Pandas' DataFrame?

For example, I want to red highlight a NaN value, but if it is not NaN, green bar is shown.

```
Score
79 --> green bar 
84 --> green bar 
nan --> red highlight
```

Currently, I can only use `highlight_null` or `apply_map` to highlight the NaN value, but don't know how to combine it with `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.bar`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I can combine it by calling the `bar` function first, and then followed by `applymap`

```
def style_zero(v, props=''):
    return props if v == 0 or v == np.nan else None

df.style.bar(color='#5fba7d').applymap(style_zero, props='background-color:pink;color:red')
```

Maybe, it will help someone who have the same concern with me.